# XSL finding a node based on value of other node + multilevel sorting

Tags: xml, xslt

Basically there are two things I need to figure out:

1. multilevel sorting
2. on the third level where I put the ???: how to select another `<term>` which has the `<title>` that equals the `<narrowerterm>` of the current `<term>`.

I hope this is clear enough. I have not been able to find what I need for some time.

#### My XML (excerpt):

```
<thesaurus>
    <term>
        <title>defense</title>
         <narrowerterm>defense skills</narrowerterm>
         <narrowerterm>defense actions</narrowerterm>
    </term>
    <term>
        <title>defense skills</title>
        <broaderterm>defense</broaderterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill cd</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill xy</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill ab</narrowerterm>
    </term>
    <term>
        <title>defense actions</title>
        <broaderterm>defense</broaderterm>
        <narrowerterm>actions against xy</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>actions against ab</narrowerterm>
    </term>
</thesaurus>
```

#### My XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="thesaurus">
<html>
<body> 
<xsl:for-each-group select="term" group-by="title">
    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="broaderterm"> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="use"> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/><br/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="narrowerterm">
                            .<xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="???"/>
                                ..<xsl:value-of select="narrowerterm"/><br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:otherwise> 
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

What I want is:

```
defense
.defense actions
..actions against ab
..actions against xy
.defense skills
..skill ab
..skill cd
..skill xy
```

Where I am is:

```
defense
.defense skills
.defense actions
```

Comment: Do not use signatures and for using XML Tags use .. Ctrl+K or `

Comment: This time I will edit it for you.

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind' This is the first post by this user. Please try to be more accommodating towards new users who may not have read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) or are aware of all the [editing features](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The question is actually well written and much better than a lot of other first questions (so +1 from me)

Comment: I feel bad for being a bit rude, actually intended to convey regulations, well. I will keep your words in mind :)

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind': Thanks for editing and sorry for not properly reading the faq and editing rules. I shall better myself in future posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a grouping task or that it requires XSLT 2.0.

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="term[not(broaderterm)]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pIndent" select="''"/>
    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="term">
  <xsl:param name="pIndent"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($pIndent, title, '&#xA;')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vSubterms" select=
      "../term[broaderterm = current()/title]"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLeafSubterms" select=
  "narrowerterm[not(. = /*/term[broaderterm = current()/title]/title)]"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSubterms | $vLeafSubterms">
   <xsl:with-param name="pIndent" select="concat($pIndent, '.')"/>
   <xsl:sort select="concat(self::term/title, self::narrowerterm/text())"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="narrowerterm">
  <xsl:param name="pIndent"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($pIndent, ., '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<thesaurus>
    <term>
        <title>defense</title>
        <narrowerterm>defense skills</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>defense actions</narrowerterm>
    </term>
    <term>
        <title>defense skills</title>
        <broaderterm>defense</broaderterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill cd</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill xy</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>skill ab</narrowerterm>
    </term>
    <term>
        <title>defense actions</title>
        <broaderterm>defense</broaderterm>
        <narrowerterm>actions against xy</narrowerterm>
        <narrowerterm>actions against ab</narrowerterm>
    </term>
</thesaurus>
```

**produces the  wanted, correct result**:

```
defense
.defense actions
..actions against ab
..actions against xy
.defense skills
..skill ab
..skill cd
..skill xy
```

Comment: @Dimitre: thanks a lot!! works! I do not yet understand everything you did, but I will try my best :-)